# How do I add multiple SVG drawing to JSVGCanvas?

Tags: java, svg, batik

This is my first attempt to play with SVG. I am using `Apache Batik` to load a svg onto a canvas using

`svgCanvas.setURI("svg/rectangle.svg");`

How do I add another SVG file for example `circle.svg` into the same canvas ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add multi svg into only one canvas using SVGDocument.
Example follow below step:

1. You read first SVG into SVGDocument:
   ex : 
   `String parser = XMLResourceDescriptor.getXMLParserClassName();`
   `SAXSVGDocumentFactory factory = new SAXSVGDocumentFactory(parser);`
   `SVGDocument svgDocument = factory.createSVGDocument(uri_svg_here);`
2. Get root element of first SVGDocument:
   ex: 
   `SVGSVGElement rootElement = svgDocument.getRootElement()`
3. Read next SVG and add all element into rootElement :
   ex:
   `Element element = svgDocument2.getRootElement();`
   `rootElement.appendChild(element);`